# Have an element always stick to the bottom of the upper one

Tags: html, css

It's a bit tricky to explain, so I've put together [**a fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/j0etvky6/7/).

[image]

While keeping Left and Right boxes vertically aligned (Left and Right boxes are correct in the picture), I need to make sure Bottom-Right boxes stick to the bottom or the Right boxes.

Put more simply : The example in the middle is what's wrong. **Red and Green boxes are fine**, but I'd want the **blue ones to always stick to the bottom of the green ones**.

Considering :

- **Left and Bottom-right** elements **can be of any height**.
- **Right** elements have a **fixed height** (30px in this case).
- I can't use any javascript for that, but I can change my HTML structure.

I've tried using `position: absolute` on the Bottom-right elements, but it creates multiple problems due to the variable heights of Left and Bottom-right elements.

I thought of using a wrapper for the Right and Bottom-right elements, but I don't know how I could align Left and Right then.

Any idea ?

Comment: Ok, could you possibly explain a little further what you're looking to achieve? As currently, (as you said yourself), it's hard to explain/see what you're trying to do. Are you looking for two columns? What are the white spaces for? Have you tried using dl's/dd's/dt's?

Comment: You can't typically do this with CSS. There are JS libraries that can help, like Masonry or Isotope.

Comment: There's no need for tags in titles, Stackoverflow takes care of that for you. For more information, please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Comment: I've edited my question, I hope it's clearer. I typically don't want to use any JS for that. If that's the only possibility, i'd rather leave it as is.

Comment: @Goodzilla please explain further. Like `jbutler483` asked, what are the white spaces for? Are you looking for two columns? How are you building the page? How exactly do the LEFT and RIGHT columns need to align? Perhaps a better visual example of what you'd like to achieve demonstrating some extremes.

Answer (score 4):

Add `float:left;` to `.left`. Also add `float:right;` to `.right`

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

ul {
    width: 600px;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

li:nth-child(even) .left {
    height: 80px;
}

li:nth-child(odd) .bottom-right {
    height: 80px;
}

.left {
    width: 250px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: LightCoral;
    float:left;      /*<- Code added here*/
}

.right {
    width: 346px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    float:right;    /*<- Code added here*/
}

.bottom-right {
    width: 346px;
    background-color: lightblue;
    float:right;
}
```

```html
<ul class="wrapper">
    <li>
        <span class="left">
            Left  (can be of any height)
        </span>
        <span class="right">
            Right (fixed height)
        </span>
        <span class="bottom-right">
            Bottom-right (can be of any height)
        </span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="left">
            Left  (can be of any height)
        </span>
        <span class="right">
            Right (fixed height)
        </span>
        <span class="bottom-right">
            Bottom-right (can be of any height)
        </span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="left">
            Left  (can be of any height)
        </span>
        <span class="right">
            Right (fixed height)
        </span>
        <span class="bottom-right">
            Bottom-right (can be of any height)
        </span>
    </li>    
</ul>
```

Comment: heh thank you :) Yeah I saw someone done that on css - but a lot work around. I found something similiar to this for you - http://codepen.io/seanjacob/pen/rmIcD - its called direction hover

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that's not what I'm looking for. I've edited my question to try to make it clearer. Red and Green boxes have to be vertically-aligned (middle).